# How to fix a JLabel transparency error?

Tags: java, swing, jlabel, transparent

I am new to Java, What I am trying to do is simple, I want to make a `JLabel` have a transparent color when the mouse enters the label area and get the label to its original color when the mouse leaves the label area.

I suppose this is simple and in my code works but I get a strange effect when the mouse is on the label. This is the code that I use:

In the event `mouseEntered` of the label:

```
private void lblNuevoCLMouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
        // TODO add your handling code here:
        bgcolor=(new Color(0, 0, 0, 100));
        lblNuevoCL.setBackground(bgcolor); 
    }
```

In the event mouseExited:

```
private void lblNuevoCLMouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
    // TODO add your handling code here:
     lblNuevoCL.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(206,206,255));
}
```

This is what happens when the mouse enters the label( the square to the left of the image):
it gets transparent using an RGB color with alpha but apart from getting transparent
a strange background appears on the label as you see in the picture.

[image]

Comment: Seems that the link is broken.

Answer (score 3):

Make the `JLabel` opaque to allow the background color to be set

```
lblNuevoCL.setOpaque(true);
```

Comment: aaargh ... You posted this a little bit quicker than me. :D But still, I posted it because I want to see my rep go up. :D

Answer (score 3):

What you need to do is to make the background of the `JLabel` magically disappear. The way to do this is to use `setOpaque()`.

What setOpaque does is this (taken from docs):

> If `true` the component paints every pixel within its bounds. 
>       Otherwise, the component may not paint some or all of its pixels, 
>       allowing the underlying pixels to show through.

The last line has the solution to your problem.
**When the mouse enters,** you use `lblNuevoCL.setOpaque(false);` to make it have a **transparent** 
background
 `lblNuevoCL.setOpaque(true);` when the **mouse exits** so that it goes back to its **original colors**. That way, you do not have to worry about what color the background is.

Remember that Ubuntu's JLabel will have a different background color than that of Windows. hardcoding the color can cause it to look weird.

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, actually i edited the opaque property of the jlabel but i did it using the ide, not with code, i dont know if that can affect

Comment: If i set the opaque property to false when the mouse enters the jlabel will get 100% transparent, i want it to be semi-transparent, that is why i use rgb color with the Alpha parameter

Comment: Then you first need to use `public Color getBackground()` to get the background color. Then, change the alpha. Remember the Ubuntu / Windows issue ? Avoid hardcoding the `int`s.

Answer (score 1):

> it gets transparent using an RGB color with alpha

See [Backgrounds With Transparency](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/05/31/backgrounds-with-transparency/) for an explanation (and a couple of solutions) of the problems you will have when you use transparency.